# Assign static IPv4 to specific MAC address

Tags: mac, router, ipv4

I am trying to assign same IPv4 to few devices every time they connect to wi-fi AP. I use Zyxel NWA3560-N. I think that there should be option to set static IP on every device and block assigning those addresses to connected devices. The problem is that I cant find this option in router settings (included in the picture).
Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: You would do it in DHCP settings, wherever they may be. Reduce the pool, then assign MAC addresses to fixed addresses outside that pool. Idk that particular device, but it looks to me like you're trying to change the ISP address, which ought to be left on automatic unless your ISP tell you otherwise.

Comment: Does the NWA3560-N have DHCP capability? It's an AP, from what I have found? If its purely an AP then you'll need a DHCP server elsewhere to be able to provide address reservation...?